# Cannot create token for the application in Netsuite?

Tags: php, access-token, netsuite

I have created many applications in Netsuite. I could get token for those applications. But now i could not get token for some applications.

When I try to get token, I got a blank message.
Even though I tried to find the reason, But I don't know why it is happening.

https://system.netsuite.com/rest/roles';

$url = 'https://system.na1.netsuite.com/rest/issuetoken?consumerKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

```
$access_token ='nlauth_account=XXXXXXX, nlauth_email=admin@example.com, nlauth_signature=password';
$header = array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization : NLAuth '.$access_token);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);exit;
```

I have only one difference between success,failed response and empty response.
Success and failed resposes are having account id 6char + 7digits on one account(Demo Version)

Empty response is having account id only 7 digits on different account (Paid Account).

I verified in Netsuite. Everthing is good. I could not even error message.

Comment: are you querying for same user for all applications or for different users?

Comment: 1. Two  Demo Version accounts are available. i could get token from the both demo version's user with the demo version's acccount's application. 2. One paid account is available. i could not get for the token from the paid account's user with paid account's application.

Comment: in the paid account what is the user's role?

Comment: I tried with two roles, no one work. Custom Sales person, Custom Marketing manger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already posted my answer for my question. Now i advise to find the url for some other accounts. Please read the following help links. This will be very useful. URL is defined based on environments

**Understanding NetSuite Environments**
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45042/kw/environments

**Understanding NetSuite URLs and Data Centers**
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42541/kw/environments

Answer (score 1):

The Url only is different for paid account. I have used url of test drive account (TSTDRV).

```
Test Drive Demo (TSTDRV) account - system.na1.netsuite.com
Paid Account - rest.netsuite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need `User Access Tokens` permission to generate/issue token in the context of a specific user.

Edit the role and you should find this permission under `Permissions > Setup` on the users role. Once, the permission is granted on their custom role they should be able to issue the tokens on their paid account

Comment: i have set everthing to get access token. The permissions are Access Token Management -> to get a token , Log in using Access Token -> After getting token to login.

Comment: Errors and description: 1. Invalid login attempt-> invalid credentials 2. Permission Violation: you may not access this record - > Access token permission is not set 3. Login access has been disabled for this role -> Log in using access token is not set . But i could not any error message

Comment: if permissions are setup and NLAuth headers are correct it should work. Also, clear cookies and try, sometimes there are multiple account conflicts

Comment: file a case with NetSuite is the last thing that can be done, ideally it should work if permissions are set correctly and `consumer key` is valid